# How to set JDK 8 for Jenkins and JDK 14 for build job?

Tags: java, jenkins, java-8, continuous-integration, java-14

I am use Jenkins 2.222.4 on Windows 2016 server.

How to set JDK 8 for Jenkins and JDK 14 for build job?
Thank you! Because I really need this type of configuration.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>java -version 
Java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server W (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\Administrator>javac -version 
javac 14.0.1 

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

[image: cmd prompt Java values]

Comment: Do you mean the job should be built using java-8 while the Jenkins should still have Java-14?

Comment: Java 8 for Jenkins.war , Java 14 for job (for example `mvn package`).

Comment: You can explore further on maven profiles and toolchains for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using OpenJDK 14 in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977072/using-openjdk-14-in-jenkins)