# Using OpenJDK 14 in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

Is it possible to use OpenJDK-14 in Jenkins (Docker version)?
I set the version in the Configurations by unpacking the JDK from this link:
https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk14/ri/openjdk-14+36_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

**This is my Jenkinsfile:**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        jdk 'jdk-14'
        maven 'Maven-3-6-3'
    }
    stages {
        stage("build project") {
            steps {
                sh 'java -version'
                echo 'building project...'
                sh 'mvn clean install'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the error i get:**

- `mvn clean install`
  The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
  This environment variable is needed to run this program
  NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

**Also the sh 'java -version' command, still gives me this:**

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can install the "[Jenkins AdoptOpenJDK installer Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/adoptopenjdk/)"

Then in your **Global Tool Configuration | Add JDK** (`${JENKINSURL}/configureTools/`), you will

- Add JDK
- tick install automatically
- Delete Installer (thereby removing the default Oracle installer)
- Add Installer
- Install from adoptOpenJDK.net
- Save

If you have more than one JDK installed, in your jobs, you should now have an option to choose JDK or specify in the  [pipeline tools](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001595227-How-To-Specify-A-Specific-JDK-In-Pipeline-) section.

Alternatively, you can just specify the path to where JDK14 is installed beforehand instead of dynamically installing.

It would seem you have the "installed beforehand" part done, but are missing the Global tool configuration, setting the path for `jdk-14`, so it's not overriding the SYSTEM default.

[image: JDK Global tool config]

*(obviously, pick from drop down or set path).*