# Steps to upgrade JDK 8 to JDK 11 for Jenkins on a Windows server?

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, java-11

I am looking for steps to upgrade java version in Jenkins windows server. I found multiple article for Linux but not for Windows.

Steps to upgrade java in Jenkins server.

Comment: please have a look  it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/72873947/7689879

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade the JDK used by Jenkins on a Windows server, you can follow these steps:

- Download the latest JDK 11 from the Oracle website and install it on your server. Be sure to choose the correct version for your operating system (i.e., Windows x64 if you are running a 64-bit version of Windows).
- Open the Jenkins configuration page by going to http://yourserver:8080/configure in your web browser, where "yourserver" is the hostname or IP address of your Jenkins server.
- In the "JDK" section, click the "Add JDK" button.
- In the "Name" field, enter a name for the new JDK (e.g., "JDK 11").
- In the "JAVA_HOME" field, enter the path to the JDK 11 installation directory. This will typically be something like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7".
- Click the "Save" button to save your changes.
- Restart Jenkins to apply the changes.

You can verify if you have required version by going to http://yourserver:8080/systemInfo in your web browser and looking for the "Java version" field in the "System Information" section. It should show the version of JDK 11 that you installed.

Comment: No, do not download JDK from Oracle unless you have an Oracle license or want Big Red on your case. Use an OpenJDK like from [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/). Also, no, the JDK you referring to has been under `/configureTools` for several years and only applies to JDK for jobs, not the one the controller or agents sun on.