# How to trowbleshoot an issue with Jenkins master, which cannot restart?

Tags: jenkins, service, restart

Jenkins doesn't come back after restart from the URL. But when you go on the machine and look at the jenkins service it is running. This is what can be seen in the jenkins.wrapper.log:

```
2023-05-23 08:21:04,574 DEBUG - Starting WinSW in the CLI mode
2023-05-23 08:21:05,293 INFO  - Restarting the service with id 'jenkins'
2023-05-23 08:21:05,465 FATAL - Unhandled exception
System.Exception: Failed to invoke restart: 193
   at winsw.WrapperService.<Run>g__RestartSelf|33_6(<>c__DisplayClass33_0& )
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)*
```

It comes back only after manual restart of the jenkins service.

The Jenkins user is also the Windows user with who I'm logged in.

Comment: hi there - would it be possible to see a bit more detail in the log?

Comment: This is the only one related to the issue. After that I restart the service manually.
Is there a way to have more detailed log for the jenkins.wrapper? I didn't find.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to double check your XML configuration of the Jenkins controller [Windows Service Wrapper](https://github.com/winsw/winsw), as illustrated in [this article](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/07/08/winsw-yaml-support/)

```xml
<service>
    <id>jenkins</id>
    <name>Jenkins</name>
    <description>This service runs Jenkins automation server.</description>
    <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%LocalAppData%\Jenkins.jenkins"/>
    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe</executable>
    <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle
    -jar "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8081 --webroot="%LocalAppData%\Jenkinswar"</arguments>
    <logmode>rotate</logmode>

    <onfailure action="restart"/>

    <extensions>
        <extension enabled="true" className="winsw.Plugins.RunawayProcessKiller.RunawayProcessKillerExtension" id="killOnStartup">
        <pidfile>%LocalAppData%\Jenkinsjenkins.pid</pidfile>
        <stopTimeout>10000</stopTimeout>
        <stopParentFirst>false</stopParentFirst>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</service>
```

As noted [in 2020](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/07/23/windows-support-updates/#jenkins-2-248-windows-support-updates)

> In theory, Jenkins can run everywhere where you can run Java 8 or Java 11, but, in practice, there are some limitations.
>
> The Jenkins core and some plugins contain native code, and hence they rely on operating systems and platforms. We use Java Native Access and Java Native Runtime libraries which provide wide platform support for low-level operations, but there are platform-specific cases not covered by such generic libraries.
>
> In the case of Windows platforms we use Windows Service Wrapper (WinSW) and [Windows Process Management Library (WinP)](https://github.com/kohsuke/winp). These libraries depend on particular Windows API versions and, in the case of Windows services, on .NET Framework.

So double-check their version. (2.9.0 at least for WinSW).

The [WinSW gitter channel](https://app.gitter.im/#/room/#winsw_winsw:gitter.im) can also help.

Comment: On Java support by Jenkins, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72786524/6309).