# How to configure jdk11 in jenkins v1.656?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want some help to configure jdk11 in jenkins v1.656.
I added an installer in "Global configuration" which points to below url for "Download URL for binary archive"

https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/13/GPL/openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

When i try to build the job using jdk11 i get the connection timeout exception. See below.

```
ERROR: Failed to download https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/13/GPL/openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz from slave;
```

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

Can someone help what other ways i can follow to add jdk11 to the jdk list in jenkins?

Comment: Wow - JDK 11 under Jenkins 1.X; interesting. Are you behind a FW and no proxy set?

Comment: jenkins 1.X is not capable of handling java 11? I have very poor knowledge on jenkins, sorry. yes we are behind firewall

Comment: I think is not related to java or jenkins. It is a network issue. Open a shell in your jenkins and try to download something public like [txt](https://bitnami.com/stack/jenkins/installer/changelog.txt) or pdf using curl: `curl http://some.url --output some.file` I used your java11 link and I downloaded without any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last Jenkins 1.x release was [2016-06-08](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/#v1.651.3). JDK11 GA was released 2018-09-25, so I would not expect smooth sailing

However, you issue is not so much running Jenkins under Java 11, rather attempting to install Java 11 as a Tool for jobs to use, which is an independent thing. Never tested that jump as not using Java 11 on our platform, but should be [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64978265/598141).

I will guess you simply don't have a proxy connection to get out to pull from java.net. Confirm from controller OS by doing a `wget` , then confgure http_proxy.

I would though recommend moving to the latest [Jenkins 2.x LTS release - 2.303.1+](https://www.jenkins.io/download/), which is fully Java 11 compatible and the default for Docker image is also now 11. 1.x has security vulnerabilities and 2.x is just so much more polished and better, especially w/pipelines and more plugins.

Mind you, you don't really want to use the GA reference release, rather some [OpenJDK implementation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK), like [hotspot/Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/). [ApodtOpenJDK installer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/adoptopenjdk/) may help.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have access rights to those servers to install jdk, it's all under control of network team. 
But can we configure nexus url in jenkins to download jdk? am not sure if it works but wanna just try.

Comment: You should really advise network team to upgrade Jenkins as it has significant vulnerabilities. If you are a Jenkins admin, you *could* upgrade from within the admin console (/manage); you should see an option to Upgrade Automatically, but I would not recommend that leap to latest unless you tried it in non-prod or can restore from backup if there's an issue. It would also need to run under Java8 (J1 typ. uses Java6), so may need network team help anyway.

Comment: Where did you read "Nexus"? Don't think you can proxy JDK d/l via Nexus. Maybe try Jenkins proxy under /pluginManager/advanced. That assumes network firewall lets you out! Engage Network ream.

Comment: yeah we might order new servers to have latest jenkins once we finish our discussions with architects. Thanks for your suggestions and help. I will get back once we finalize our discussions with architects and network team