# Jenkins does not support Java 16

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, build, developer-tools

Jenkins doesn't support after java 12. But I need to keep continue with Java 16 for my project.

It looks little bit hard but is there any way to accomplish that. Do you have idea to do with Dind (Docker in docker)

[image: Java requirements]
[Java requirements](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/)

Comment: This reads like Jenkins needs a long-term support version to _run_ but you should be able to provide additional Java versions for your _builds_. In fact the page states as much: "There are separate run and job execution requirements for Jenkins installations.", "Jenkins jobs may be executed on Java versions different from the controller/agent runtime." but also "If you use Maven Integration Plugin, version of the JDK used for the build must be equal to the version used by Jenkins". - So it _is_ possible to build your project with Java 16 but you might not be able to use some of the plugins.

Comment: Btw, "supported" may mean "it doesn't run on those" or "we didn't test with those and thus if anything breaks you're warned". Do you know which of the 2 it is, i.e. does Jenkins start up with Java 16 or does it check the version and won't come up?

Comment: You are confusing running Jenkins on Java and [using Java within Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977072/using-openjdk-14-in-jenkins/64978265#64978265). Not an issue and answered before.

Comment: Besides, as soon as Java LTS 17 was released, 16 was deprecated and no longer supported; consider moving your project to 17, while running Jenkins on 11.

Comment: @IanW thank you, u really saved me. I couldn't find this question on my searches. Open JDK plugin solves this problem

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the [Java requirements](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java) page you reference (by image), there's the section on "Running Jenkins" and the section on "[Executing jobs on Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/#executing-jobs-on-jenkins)", which mentions *"build steps using JDK managed by JDK tool installers"*. I suppose it could have a link to the  [JDK tool installers](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search?query=JDK%20tool%20installers) or be more clear..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answers, Solution is possible Open JDK plugin solved the problem.

Here is the question where I found solution: [Using OpenJDK 14 in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977072/using-openjdk-14-in-jenkins)