# Is there any workaround to run Java 7 in latest Jenkins (version 2.303.3)?

Tags: java, jenkins

Since the latest Jenkins will not support Java 7 is there any other way to run builds that have older java versions like Java 7?

Comment: Run Jenkins under Java 8 (or 11) install Java 7 as a Global Tool for [use by the jobs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/#executing-jobs-on-jenkins)

Comment: Just replace "Java 14" with Java 7 - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64978265/598141)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using OpenJDK 14 in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977072/using-openjdk-14-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to download the Jenkins source code and rewrite it to avoid using any Java 8 features (which it uses, that's why it needs Java 8).  Then you can recompile it to Java 7 and run it on your Java 7 virtual machine.

Or you can just update your Java 7 JVM to Java 8, because Java 7 went end-of-life in 2015.

Now if the code Jenkins is managing is old and requires Java 7, the setup the jobs within Jenkins to use Java 7 but allow Jenkins to use a newer JVM.

Comment: @IanW The irony is not lost, but keep in mind this is a person administering a Jenkins server on Java7.  I imagine the last time they tried to update anything (or even look in the server in detail) was 2015.  They might need a lot of hand holding.  I don't intend to hold their hands, but I will point them in the right direction.  They can google the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The thing is we are using java 8 for all of our latest branches. There is one older branch, we got a request to reuse it for a particular customer who has code in java 7. will try out the ideas mentioned above.

Comment: @ramesh The best option might be to put a team on it for a couple of weeks to upgrade it to build under Java 8.  But really, your problems are about to get much bigger.  Java 11 is about to be the oldest long term supported version of Java out there.  Java's up to 17 now.  It's time to see if those old projects can be updated.

Comment: sure will discuss this with our team for the permanent fix, even we didn't expect this. Thanks for your assistance @EdwinBuck.

Comment: @ramesh, you can simply use the appropriately installed and configured [JDK tool](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search?sort=relevance&categories=&labels=&view=Tiles&page=1&query=JDK%20tool). Alternatively, you can use the `javac -source <value> -target <value> -release <value>` [options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), also available via [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Comment: @EdwinBuck, depending if you look at [Oracle Extended Supprot](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html), [OpenJDK via RedHat Suppot](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013#OpenJDK_Life_Cycle) or [ApdoptOpenJDK via IBM Support](https://adoptopenjdk.net/support.html), Java 8 appears to have at least as long as or longer planned support than 11 or 17, so moving from 8 is not likely a priority issue on its own